# foreach category echo results

Tags: php, mysql

i'm attempting to list my suppliers in order, with showing the items that I need to order under the supplier. But the script originally provided to me lists the supplier each time.

This is what i've got:

```
$dataSQL = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE product_active='Y' ORDER BY product_supplier, product_category, product_code ASC";

        $data = mysql_query($dataSQL) or die(mysql_error());  
        $rows = mysql_num_rows($data); 

        while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) { 

            $category=$result['product_category'];
            $id=$result['id'];
            $item1=$result['product_name'];
            $code1=$result['product_code'];
            $code2=$result['product_suppliercode'];
            $soh=$result['product_soh'];
            $reorder=$result['product_reorder'];
            $supplier=$result['product_supplier'];
            $order=$result['product_reorder']-$result['product_soh'];

            // output row from database
            if($soh<$reorder) {
                echo "
                <tr><td>$supplier</td><td>SOH $soh | Order $order</td></tr>
                <tr><td>$item1</td><td>$code1</td></tr>
                ";
                }
        }
```

However, if there is more than 1 product low on stock from 1 supplier, i only want to list the supplier once, not every time.

This is the current result:
Low & Out of Stock Report
Biz Supplies SOH 3 | Order 1
White Thermal Travel Mug 0000000001030
Office Works SOH 14 | Order 1
Frixion Stamp Coffee Cup (Orange) 4902505508073
Office Works SOH 0 | Order 1
Frixion Stamp Apple 4902505508103
PHE (Paper Handling Equipment) SOH | Order 1
20mm 100pk Plastic Binding Comb
(box)
0000000004115

(sorry, not sure how to display here in table format). The end result would be that it would show the supplier name once, then on the next row show the item, code, soh & reorder

Comment: Can you show us your output and I believe you are looking for a `GROUP BY` or want to execute two queries (one to select the supplier and one to select the products).

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated and removed in PHP7 - I'd advise migrating to PDO or mysqli (personally pref PDO)

Comment: What you want is called a _control break_ … and is pretty simple to implement, you just need to compare the relevant value of the current record with that of the previous one. If they are the same, you don’t output it.

Answer (score 0):

You can select `DISTINCT` `product_supplier`. 
So your query will become:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON product_supplier * 
FROM inventory 
WHERE product_active='Y' 
ORDER BY product_supplier, product_category, product_code ASC
```

Alternatively, you can use a `GROUP BY` on the column that you want to eliminate duplicates:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM inventory 
WHERE product_active='Y' 
GROYP BY product_supplier
ORDER BY product_supplier, product_category, product_code ASC
```

Comment: Option 1 came up with a error and to check my php version. Option 2 displayed no results sadly.

Comment: Can you run the queries on a database level first?

Comment: @Patrick that's not the SQL - SQL isn't affected by php version

Comment: The second one worked in mysql. Showed me a few more items that were out of stock, but I suspect it's because on the webpage it has another criteria to not show specific items.

Comment: @Patrick You need to figure out why the query is working on database level but not in your php code.